# Control Node-Red with button on wordpress, HTTP Get

Tags: wordpress, http, get, network-programming, node-red

So, Im working on something, and I need to basically control node red with a button on my wordpress site. Did a little research and it looks like http is the way to go. Problem is, I know nothing about it. So I managed to send a value to node red by putting the following into a browser-

localhost:1880/test/?value=1

Here is the flow-

```
[{"id":"a247c8e.caffb38","type":"tab","label":"Flow 2","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"93b2ec9.0acfa1","type":"debug","z":"a247c8e.caffb38","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":470,"y":160,"wires":[]},{"id":"a3129f89.1dfe3","type":"http in","z":"a247c8e.caffb38","name":"","url":"test","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":160,"y":160,"wires":[["93b2ec9.0acfa1"]]}]
```

But now Im stuck. 2 questions-

1- If I just put that link in a button on the site, it will work, but it will try to go to that site and then give an error. I dont want to go to that site, I want to stay on the site where the button is. Do I need to send some type of http response to say "Got it, now stay on the same site" or something? How?

2- How do I make this work from another network? Do I need to do something like-

publicIP/localIP/port/test/?value=1

Something like that?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to make the request using Javascript from the Wordpress page. You can attach a `onclick` listener to the button and then use a `XMLHttpRequest` to trigger the listener. There are plenty examples of using `XMLHttpRequest` online.
2. Assuming you are running Node-RED on a device inside your home network then you will need to set up some form port forwarding on your router to expose the Node-RED instance to the outside. Before doing this you MUST enable the Admin Authentication which will require a username/password to access the Node-RED editor. Without this you run the risk of hackers gaining access and installing a cryto miner.

   You will also need either a static IP address or a DynamicDNS solution if you want this to work for anybody on the internet.

Comment: Seems more complicated than I thought/than it should need to be. Is there an easier way? Maybe a wp plugin? And it doesnt need to be http get, it could be whatever that works. It doesnt really even need to go to node red. Basically, I need it to send something over mqtt on my home network when the button is clicked.

Comment: Not really, you could go direct to MQTT from the WordPress page, but even that is going to need Javascript in the page and opening up the MQTT broker to the outside world and probably enabling MQTT over WebSockets on the broker. And again you'll need either a static IP or DynamicDNS